# perl shasum vs bash shasum

Tags: bash, perl, sha

The following bash and Perl scripts mysteriously give different results. Why?

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                       
hash=`echo -n 'abcd' | /usr/bin/shasum -a 256`;
echo $hash;

#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                   
$hash = `echo -n 'abcd' | /usr/bin/shasum -a 256`;
print "$hash";
```

The bash script:

```
$ ./tst.sh
88d4266fd4e6338d13b845fcf289579d209c897823b9217da3e161936f031589 -
```

The Perl script:

```
$ ./tst.pl
61799467ee1ab1f607764ab36c061f09cfac2f9c554e13f4c7442e66cbab9403  -
```

the heck?

Comment: Give the full path to `echo`. Otherwise you'll be using the bash built-in in one case, and possibly something else in the other case.

Comment: You're picky - the 2 have much the same 16 characters in them ;-)

Comment: Yep. Used `/bin/echo` -- this kind of stuff keeps me up at night.

Comment: @mark-setchell I just like to complain.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Summary: In your Perl script, `-n` is being treated as an argument to include in the output of `echo`, not a flag to suppress the newline. ( Try

```
$hash = `echo -n 'abcd'`;
```

to confirm). Use `printf` instead.

---

Perl uses `/bin/sh` to execute code in back tics. Even if `/bin/sh` is a link to `bash`, it will behave differently when invoked via that like. In POSIX mode,

```
echo -n 'abcd'
```

will output

```
-n abcd
```

that is, the `-n` option is not recognized as a flag to suppress a newline, but is treated as a regular argument to print. Replace `echo -n` with `printf` in each script, and you should get the same SHA hash from each script.

(UPDATE: `bash` 3.2, when invoked as `sh`, displays this behavior. Newer versions of `bash` seem to continue treating `-n` as a flag when invoked as `sh`.)

---

Even better, don't shell out to do things you can do in Perl.

```
use Digest::SHA;

$hash = Digest::SHA::sha256('abcd');
```

---

For the curious, here's what the POSIX spec [has to say](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) about `echo`. I'm not sure what to make of XSI conformance; `bash` `echo` requires the `-e` option to treat the escape characters specially, but nearly every shell—*except* old versions of `bash`, and then only under special circumstances—treats `-n` as a flag, not a string. Oh well.

```
The following operands shall be supported:

string
A string to be written to standard output. If the first operand is -n, or
if any of the operands contain a <backslash> character, the results are
implementation-defined.

On XSI-conformant systems, if the first operand is -n, it shall be treated
as a string, not an option. The following character sequences shall be
recognized on XSI-conformant systems within any of the arguments:

\a
Write an <alert>.
\b
Write a <backspace>.
\c
Suppress the <newline> that otherwise follows the final argument in the output. All characters following the '\c' in the arguments shall be ignored.
\f
Write a <form-feed>.
\n
Write a <newline>.
\r
Write a <carriage-return>.
\t
Write a <tab>.
\v
Write a <vertical-tab>.
\\
Write a <backslash> character.
\0num
Write an 8-bit value that is the zero, one, two, or three-digit octal number num.
```

Comment: You caught me while looking up which module did SHA sums :)

Comment: Interesting, on my machine (which probably has a slightly customized version of `bash`, but is version 4.3.25+), running `sh -c "echo -n 'abcd'"` produces the same output as `bash -c "echo -n 'abcd'"` (without a newline and without a `-n` in the output).

Comment: Yeah, I think this might have been a slight bug in older versions of `bash`. Even in 3.2, `bash --posix -c 'echo -n abcd'` treats `-n` as a flag, versus `sh -c 'echo -n abcd'` which doesn't.

Comment: I replaced `echo` with `/bin/echo` and it worked. Subtle. I did use Digest::SHA instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

If you do:

```
printf "%s" 'abcd' | /usr/bin/shasum -a 256
```

you get the 88d...589 hash.  If you do:

```
printf "%s\n" '-n abcd' | /usr/bin/shasum -a 256
```

you get the 617...403 hash.

Therefore, I deduce that Perl is somehow running a different `echo` command, perhaps `/bin/echo` or `/usr/bin/echo` instead of the `bash` built-in `echo`, or maybe the built-in echo to `/bin/sh` (which might perhaps be `dash` rather than `bash`), and this other `echo` does not recognize the `-n` option as an option and outputs different data.

I'm not sure which other `echo` it is finding; on my machine which is running an Ubuntu 14.04 LTE derivative, `bash`, `dash`, `sh` (linked to `bash`), `ksh`, `csh` and `tcsh` all treat `echo -n abcd` the same way.  But somewhere along the line, I think that there is something along these lines happening; the hash checksums being identical strongly point to it.  (Maybe you have a 3.2 `bash` linked to `sh`; see the notes in the comments.)

Comment: When invoked as `sh`, `bash` 3.2 does not recognize `-n` as a flag, but `bash` 4.1 and later (and maybe 4.0 as well, probably) do. Your `sh` might be linked to a newer version of `bash`, although I though it was usually linked to `dash` in Ubuntu.

Comment: What I'm using isn't a completely standard Ubuntu 14.04 release; it has been re-engineered in part by the company.  The `bash` is fixed with the Shell Shock fix, though its version claims to be `4.3.11(1)`, and `/bin/sh` _is_ a link to `/bin/bash`.  (There are some other oddities about date of release vs Shell Shock, but the basic Shell Shock repro shows the 'fixed' output.)

Comment: I replaced `echo` with `/bin/echo` and difference went away. Thanks.